# Getting error when try to find existing product from localStorage in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cart

I am trying to implement a cart system using localStorage, the codes are below, how I trying to achieve that

```
const data = {
    description: "Cum sociis natoque",
    mediaUrl: "/products-img7.jpg",
    name: "Hearing Aid Device",
    newProduct: true,
    onOffer: "5",
    onSale: true,
    price: "99.57",
    productType: "medical",
    sku: "534-20-2675",
    viewCount: 0,
    _id: "5f095b0bd7f2be792ee6ba1c",
}

const handleAddToCart = (data, quantity = 1) => {
    let getCarts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCart'))
    let existed_item = null
    if(getCarts || getCarts != null){
        existed_item = getCarts.find(item => item._id == data._id) // Error in that line
    }

    if (existed_item) {
        let cartItem = Object.assign({}, existed_item, {quantity: (quantity + existed_item.quantity)})
        localStorage.setItem('myCart', JSON.stringify(cartItem))
    } else {
        let cartProducts = new Array()
        if(localStorage.getItem('myCart')){
            cartProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCart'))
        }
        let dataWQty = Object.assign({}, data, {quantity: quantity});
        let newCartProducts = [...cartProducts, dataWQty]

        localStorage.setItem('myCart',JSON.stringify(newCartProducts));
    }
}
```

from above codes getting below error

```
Unhandled Runtime Error <br/>
TypeError: getCarts.find is not a function
```

How can I overcome that situation now? I really want a help to solve that.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What does `console.log(getCarts);` right before you call `.find` output? Maybe it's just not a valid array, or not even an array at all.

Comment: What is the result of `localStorage.getItem('myCart')`?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi in console showing exactly the 'data` variable like!

Comment: @jesica `data` you pasted above is an object, not an array, and objects have no method called `find`.

Comment: In one set item 'myCart' is object in the other one 'myCart' is array. .find will work fine when its array but when its an object only in that case you are getting this error ?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi when updating an existing item with `quantity` first action is good but after that getting error!

Comment: @Subhadeep Yes, after the match this `if (existed_item)` the array resetting with `Object`  can you please suggest me what should I do in that line?

Comment: what does your getCarts look like ?

Comment: @jesica is `localStorage.getItem('myCart')` supposed to be an object or an array of objects?

Comment: @aravind_reddy it should an array & it is but after updating quantity it's going to reset and making an `object`

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi supposed to be an Array & it does for new item creating, the issue came when update quantity for an item

Comment: The problem is when you do find a match exiting in cart you update the quantity count and simply stringify the updated object. To solve this once you find a match then you also need to track the position of the item in the cart array. Then update the quantity of the exiting object, now with the index replace the old object in array with the updated object present in the cart array. Then stringify the entire array once more and set it to local storage. Hope this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change your logic for updating the items while you are getting array at first but you are replacing it with an object when you are first updating it

```
let getCarts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCart'))
let existed_item_index = -1
if(getCarts || getCarts != null){
    existed_item_index = getCarts.findIndex(item => item._id === data._id)
}

if (existed_item_index!==-1) {
    const updatedCarts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getCarts));
    updatedCarts[existed_item_index].quantity += quantity;
    localStorage.setItem('myCart', JSON.stringify(updatedCarts));
}
```

Comment: I suppose you mean `JSON.stringify(updatedCarts)` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer & I have update slightly from your code and now it's fine

Comment: yeah you could do that but in my opinion, it is best to create a new object without any references for the previous object so that it wont create any problems going forward

Comment: Can you please guide me why when I try get count of object it's showing a long number like for one object of the array it's showing `60` something

Comment: what do you mean by `try to get count of the object` it will be great if you could add another question if you have some other problem.i will be happy to help